# Modify Eclipse UI from plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm building a plugin for eclipse which performs some static analysis on the projects currently found in the workspace. I have an implementation of `AbstractHandler`, the `execute` method is called when my button is pressed in Eclipse.

Once my analysis has been completed, for now, I want a new text window to open in Eclipse with the output of the analysis.

I've followed the vogella tutorial here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html#eclipsejobs_uisynchronize
which explains that I need to inject a `UISynchronizer` object (or rather, eclipse will inject it for me) and call the `asynch(Runnable)` method from the handler. However, when I import `UISynchronizer`, Eclipse gives the warning:

`Discouraged access: The type UISynchronizer is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.105.2.v20140211-1711.jar`

Is this to discourage the average user from using the `UISynchronizer` class? Or should I be using a different method to update the UI from my handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UISynchronizer` is for a Eclipse e4 style application, since you are using `AbstractHandler` you must be writing an Eclipse 3.x style plugin so it is not an appropriate thing to use.

Instead use `Display.asyncExec`:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(runnable);
```

This is actually what `UISynchronizer` uses internally.

For the record the 'Discouraged access' warning is because the `UISynchronizer` interface has not yet been finalized and might change. For an e4 application this warning can be ignored.

Update:

Checking again the e4 class is `UISynchronize` not `UISynchronizer` which is an internal class and should not be used at all.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm new to eclipse plugin development, and appear to be using parts of both the e4 and 3.x styles. I think I should fix that!